# Longest word in a txt file python code?

Tags: python

This is my version of this program. Is there a shorter and simpler way to do this?

```
d = open('txt.txt','r')
l = d.readlines()
string = l[0]
stringsplit = string.split()

d = []
for i in stringsplit:
    d.append(len(i))
    e = max(d)
for j in stringsplit:
    if len(j) == e:
        print("The longest word is", j, "and it is", len(j),"characters long")
```

Comment: How is that finding the longest word in the entire text file? Are you not only checking `l[0]`, which is the first line in the text file? Correct me if I am wrong. Also, if you want to do this manually, there really is no need to do `d.append(len(i))` before finding the `max` in the array. You can always start with `maxLen = 0` and then if `len(i) > maxLen`, `maxLen = len(i)`, `e = i` and update as you go. (There is no need to lop through `stringsplit` twice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions to turn the input into a single list and then use reduce on the resulting list to find the longest string.

```
f = open("input.txt", "r")
s = [y for x in f.readlines() for y in x.split()]
longest = reduce(lambda x, y: y if len(x) < len(y) else x, s, "")
print("The longest word is", longest, "and it is", len(longest),"characters long")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max()` built-in function:

```
longest = max(stringsplit, key=len)
print("The longest word is {} and it is {} characters long".format(longest, len(longest)))
```

It is worth noting, however, that `stringsplit` is a list of the words in just the first line of the file, not the whole file itself.  If you want it to be all of the words, use `stringsplit = d.read().split()`